# Is there a point to restrict values in limited queries on big tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a multiple similar tables with thousands of rows, and I do queries like this

```
select * from firsttable where firsttable.type = :rt
union
select * from secondtable where secondtable.type = :rt
...
order by exp desc limit 50;
```

For every type there is a certain exp limit that could be set to restrict amount of rows look into.

Will this filter query modification increase query performance?

```
select * from firsttable where exp > $expFilter and firsttable.type = :rt
union
select * from secondtable where exp > $expFilter and secondtable.type = :rt
...
order by exp desc limit 50;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$expFilter` filters out a significant number of rows, it could make a difference because there would be fewer rows to sort in the `order by`. How much of a difference it makes would depend on whether `exp` is indexed or not.